# Cannot upload file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have problems to upload a file:

Here is my html:

```
<%= form_tag import_test_path, multipart: true do %>
 <%= file_field_tag :file, :style => 'display:inline; margin-top:-10px' %>
 <%= submit_tag 'Hochladen', :class => 'btn btn-sm btn-info' %>
<% end %>
```

First i tried to simply upload it and to handle it in my controller like this:

```
  def import
    widgets = DBF::Table.new(params[:file], nil, 'cp1252')
    w = widgets.find(6)
    p = Patient.new
    p.vorname = w.vorname
    p.name = w.name
    p.geburtsdatum = w.geburt
    p.save
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html {redirect_to :back }
    end  
  end
```

But this provoced an error:

```
 no implicit conversion of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String
 in line: DBF::Table.new(params[:file], nil, 'cp1252')
```

Next i tried to generate first an Tempfile:

```
def import
    file = Tempfile.new(params[:file])
    widgets = DBF::Table.new(file, nil, 'cp1252')
    w = widgets.find(6)
    p = Patient.new
    p.vorname = w.vorname
    p.name = w.name
    p.geburtsdatum = w.geburt
    p.save
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html {redirect_to :back }
    end  
  end
```

But this also proved an error:

```
 unexpected prefix_suffix: #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x6793d10 @tempfile=#  <Tempfile:C:/Users/EMMANU~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20131110-6816-ogkd3i>, @original_filename="patient.DBF", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"patient.DBF\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n">
 in line: file = Tempfile.new(params[:file])
```

What do i wrong? Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing `params[:file]` is a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` which is just a wrapper for the TmpFile that is used to store the uploaded content.

You need to `read` from that IO like object to get the contents.

Comment: Can you describe me how i should read from the tempfile? The strange thing is that when i run `DBF::Table.new("filename.dbf", nil, 'cp1252')` locally i also only pass a `filename.dbf` file

Comment: I'm getting the string contains null byte issue as well. Did you ever figure it out @JohnSmith ?

Comment: @pav no sorry! At the end i found other solution that i cannot remember!

Answer (score 0):

Try `DBF::Table.new(params[:file].path, nil, 'cp1252')`