# Read uploaded JSON file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm uploading a JSON file in Rails in order to parse it and then insert into the database without storing the file itself

Form

```
= form_tag import_posts_path do
  = file_field_tag :file
  = submit_tag "import"
```

Controller method

```
def import
  file = params[:file]

  puts "file => " + file # file => posts.json

  data = File.read(params[:file]) # Errno::ENOENT at /posts/import No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - posts.json

  json = JSON.parse(data)
end
```

routes

```
resources :posts do
  collection { post :import }
end
```

request info in Terminal, and the `posts.json` is there but I get `Errno::ENOENT at /posts/import No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - posts.json`

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9lzpwyCWclgiI4WA/zho5y1WLCBQtRL7z3FcAn+wc80=", "file"=>"posts.json", "commit"=>"import"}
file => posts.json
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms
```

Comment: You should send it as multipart form data

Comment: See if this thread is of any assistance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521053/how-to-read-a-user-uploaded-file-without-saving-it-to-the-database

Comment: Thanks @usmanali this did the trick plus a new work in the method

Comment: Thanks @xenover this helps too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution:

Update the form to send the file as multipart form data as @usmanali advised

```
= form_tag import_posts_path, multipart: true do
  = file_field_tag :file
  = submit_tag "import"
```

and then in the controller just `read` directly into `params[:file]` as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19893804/558777)

```
def import
  file = params[:file].read
  data = JSON.parse(file)
end
```